# The function Input.GetMouseButtonDown id true for two frames consecutively in Unity3D. Why

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a code like the following:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        Debug.Log("foo");
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I click the right mouse button once the "foo" is written twice. How is it possible?

Comment: it looks like it's true two times consecutively

Comment: In your scene you have just one GameObject attached with this component/script? If you have 2 objects with this same behaviour in scene it will print 2 times and so on... Check if you doesn't have this script twice in same scene ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Frohlich stated in comment, If you attach a script on more than one GameObject you will be getting Update method call per frame for each script in scene. So to check that you should use `Debug.Log()` method as follow:

```
Debug.Log("foo",gameObject);
```

and when you will click on log in console window, it will take you to the gameObject which is generating that log.

Comment: Yes! You guys are correct! My script was attched to two game objects, that's why it was executes twice per frame!